# "не то" в значении "иначе" выделяется пунктуационно?

Tags: пунктуация

"не то" в значении "иначе" выделяется пунктуационно?
Примеры:
1."Уходи, не то (?) поссоримся"
2."Уходи, не то (?) беда!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Уходи, не то поссоримся. Уходи, не то беда!***

Это сложносочиненные предложения с **разделительными** союзами, но в них выражено особое значение, которое называется **альтернативной мотивацией**.

В этом случае используются союзы **ИЛИ,  ЛИБО, А ТО,  А НЕ ТО и союзные аналоги ИНАЧЕ, В ПРОТИВНОМ СЛУЧАЕ**.

**Запятая ставится** между простыми предложениями перед союзом.